# python subprocess.call[] can't do operations over files with spaces

Tags: python, for-loop, space, cp

I have a list of files inside a directory on Linux:

```
files 1.pdf
files 2.pdf
files.pdf
files 3.pdf
```

I have assigned all inside a list:

```
>>> files_destino = [f for f in os.listdir("./espacio/")]
```

when I do for-loop it does list the files even though it has spaces.

```
   >>> for i in files_destino:
...     print i
... 
files 1.pdf
files 2.pdf
files.pdf
files 3.pdf
```

But when I'm trying to do a "cp" or "rsync" or any other command over them it appears as though they don't exist except for the ones with NO spaces.

```
    >>> for i in files_destino:
...     subprocess.call(["cp","-v",i,"/tmp/"])
... 
cp: files 1.pdf: No such file or directory
1
cp: files 2.pdf: No such file or directory
1
files.pdf -> /tmp/files.pdf
0
cp: files 3.pdf: No such file or directory
1
```

Any reason of this behaviour?

Thanks

---

Here are the output from the suggestions.

```
   >>> subprocess.call(["cp","-v",'"'+i+'"',"/tmp/"])
cp: "files 1.pdf": No such file or directory
1
>>> subprocess.call(["cp","-v",'"{}"'.format(i),"/tmp/"])
cp: "files 1.pdf": No such file or directory
1
```

Comment: have you tried adding quotes around the file name? `'"'+i+'"'`

Comment: Better yet, use [`shutil.copyfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html)

Comment: works for me. which OS do you use?

Comment: This kinda surprises me.  Is `cp` an alias?  I wonder if its passing the variables is what's causing the space expansion.  If you us `/bin/cp` instead of `cp` does it work as expected?

Comment: Mac Os X 10.10, Python 2.7.6

Comment: >>> subprocess.call(["/bin/cp","-v",'"'+i+'"',"/tmp/"])         
cp: "files 1.pdf": No such file or directory
1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cp: files 1.pdf: No such file or directory
```

The file `files 1.pdf` isn't inside the current directory. It's inside the directory you listed, `./espacio/`. If `files.pdf` worked, it's only because by coincidence there was also a `files.pdf` inside the currect directory.

```
parent_path = './espacio/'
for file_name in os.listdir(parent_path):
    file_path = os.path.join(parent_path, file_name)
    subprocess.call(["cp", "-v", file_path ,"/tmp/"])
```

However, as @Colonel Thirty Two commented, it's generally a better idea to do the copying inside Python rather than using a shell command when you can.

Comment: What about if instead "cp" I want to use "rsync" command or "md5" command?

Comment: @x1c70r: You do the same thing: just path the file *path* e.g. `espacio/files 1.pdf`, not just the file name e.g. `files 1.pdf` and you'll be fine.

Comment: @x1c70r first, don't edit the answer to respond to it. Second, the answer said "*when you can.*" Python includes an [`md5`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/md5.html) module, and there are 3rd-party modules for `rsync`, although you can certainly call the command-line version if you wish. Get to know the std lib, use [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org), and google everything.

Comment: To calculate MD5 hash, `import hashlib` and `hashlib.md5(open(filename, 'rb').read()).hexdigest()`. Rsync isn't built into the standard library, so to avoid the command line for that you'd have to use a third-party module.

Comment: Thank you all you guys! Let me figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

With your solution @bobince now can do it as wanted also with MD5.

```
def onepath(archivo):
    logging.basicConfig(filename=salida,filemode="w", format='%(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)
    for file_name in os.listdir(archivo):
            #se obtiene la ruta relativa de todos los archivos que estan dentro de esa carpeta
            file_path = os.path.join(archivo, file_name)
            print file_path
            with open(file_path) as checkfile:
                    logging.info("MD5" + "(%s) = " % file_name + hashlib.md5(checkfile.read()).hexdigest())
```